# Android Volley gives me 400 error

Tags: android, rest, android-volley

I'm trying to make a `POST` request to my API and it works in `Postman` (I get a valid JSON object), but not using `Volley`. With the following code:

```
String URL = "http://somename/token";
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(StartActivity.this);
queue.add(new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST, URL, null,
   new Listener<JSONObject>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
           // handle response
           Log.i("StartActivity", response.toString());
       }
   }, new ErrorListener() {
       @Override
       public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
           // handle error   
           Log.i("StartActivity", error.toString());
       }
   }) {

   @Override
   public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
       HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
       headers.put("username", "someUsername");
       headers.put("password", "somePassword");
       headers.put("Authorization", "Basic someCodeHere");
       return headers;
   }
   @Override
    protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("grant_type", "client_credentials");

            return params;
        }
   });
```

I get the following error:

```
02-12 21:42:54.774: E/Volley(19215): [46574] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for http://somename/token/
```

I have seen a lot of examples and I don't really see what is going wrong here. Anyone any idea?

**I updated the code with this method:**

```
HashMap<String, String> createBasicAuthHeader(String username, String password) {
        HashMap<String, String> headerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        String credentials = username + ":" + password;
        String base64EncodedCredentials =
                Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        headerMap.put("Authorization", "Basic " + base64EncodedCredentials);

        return headerMap;
    }
```

and changed `getHeaders()` to:

```
@Override
   public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
       return createBasicAuthHeader("username", "password");
   }
```

Still getting the same error!

Comment: are you sure you're putting in the auth headers correctly? if you're using basic auth you should be base64 encoding the username:password I believe

Comment: @panini I'm already setting the base64 code as "somecodehere".

Comment: @just8laze I'm just using Android's AsyncTask. It's much simpler and it works perfect. See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example

Comment: @Loolooii Yeah, I already have it working with AsyncTask and HttpPost. No idea why it doesn't work with Volley. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @just8laze I'm glad that worked for you and you're welcome.

Comment: @Loolooii: Have you solved this issue? I am also facing the exact same problem. It will be helpful if you can explain how you solved this issue. Thanks.

Comment: @roymathew I ended up using AsyncTask class, but if you want a library you can use this: http://loopj.com/android-async-http/. Honestly I haven't tried to use Volley anymore.

Comment: Carefully check your JSON request. In my case, it was malformed, hence the error.

Answer (score 23):

I had the same problem and i removed from the header:

```
  headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

now it works great!

Comment: Waoooo... awesome... its great

Comment: Most of the time passing content type in headers wouldn't work, So you must need to override this method to declare the content type:
`getBodyContentType()`

Comment: I was facing issue of 400-Bad request reason I was sending "content-Type" ,"application/json" in headers so this issue resolved by removing content type from headers.

Answer (score 9):

If you are passing the json value to in body(raw json).No need to set the content type as  headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

When I was using the content type in header callback  ,the 400 response status I was getting in logcat.I commented  headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"); as because I am passing raw json in body while calling api.screenshot for postman is attached.It will help

```
private void volleyCall(String email, String password) {

      RequestQueue queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
      String URL = "http://XXXX.in:8080/XXXX/api/userService/login";

      Map<String, String> jsonParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
      jsonParams.put("email", email);
      jsonParams.put("password", password);
      Log.d(TAG,"Json:"+ new JSONObject(jsonParams));

      JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest( Request.Method.POST, URL,new JSONObject(jsonParams),
              new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                  @Override
                  public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                      Log.d(TAG,"Json"+ response);
                  }
              },
              new Response.ErrorListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                      //   Handle Error
                      Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + error
                              + "\nStatus Code " + error.networkResponse.statusCode
                              + "\nResponse Data " + error.networkResponse.data
                              + "\nCause " + error.getCause()
                              + "\nmessage" + error.getMessage());
                  }
              }) {
          @Override
          public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
              HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String,String>();
             // headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
              return headers;
          }
          @Override
          public String getBodyContentType() {
              return "application/json";
          }



      };

      queue.add(postRequest);

  }
```

---

```
LogCat:
LoginActivity: Json:{"email":"XXXXXX@gmail.com","password":"abcde"}
LoginActivity: Error: com.android.volley.ServerError
                                                                          
Status Code 400                                                                     
Response Data [B@63ca992                                                                              
Cause null                                                                              
messagenull
```

[image]

Comment: thanks that's exactly what was happening with me, your answer saved me from hours of head scratching.

Comment: i got same thing as u
but how to manage to get the response from server and not  [B@63ca992

Answer (score 6):

There can be multiple reasons for this error.

One reason, of course, as said by others, is that maybe you are missing or have improperly set 'Content-type' header.

If you have properly implemented that, another possible reason is that you are sending params directly from your URL. There may be a case when params is a string with some white spaces in it. These white spaces cause problems in GET requests through Volley. You need to find another way around it. That's all.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11974307)

Comment: This answer worked for me. That is why I posted it here.

Comment: This answer is very helpful. The get request url-with-space problem is very tricky. Very thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 4):

400 error is because Content-Type is set wrong.
Please do the following.

1. GetHeader function should be as

   ```
       @Override
       public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

           Map<String, String> param = new HashMap<String, String>();

           return param;
       }
   ```
2. Add this new override function.

   ```
       @Override
       public String getBodyContentType() {
           return "application/json";
       }
   ```

Comment: After spending a couple of hours on this, it is very important that the getHeaders()-method does NOT contain a "Content-Type" header, aside from having to add the getBodyContentType()-method, that is the most important part of this answer. Other headers can be present in the getHeaders()-method however.

Answer (score 3):

400 indicates a bad request, maybe you're missing `Content-Type=application/json` on your headers

Comment: it's something else, `JsonRequest` has that by default

Comment: I think @thepoosh is right, anyway I tried it and still getting the same error.

Comment: @thepoosh its not a server error, its a bad request which means if anything its a client error

Comment: I meant to say, server initiated error, meaning the API was misused

Comment: @panini I checked the logs and there's nothing. I do the exact same thing in Postman and it works.

Comment: @Loolooii do you have access to the server? I would suggest checking to see if the request does actually match the one seen in Postman. If you don't have access to it, then [mitmproxy](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy) is good for checking requests. I get the feeling that the request being sent from Volley won't match the Postman one

Comment: @panini yes I have, it's hosted on Heroku and I just checked the logs. There's no problem at all.

Comment: @Loolooii, have you tried `Accept=application/json`?

Comment: @LeonardoPinto I get a TimeoutError. Do you know how I can fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue before and I got the solution in my project:

```
RequestQueue requestManager = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        String requestURL = "http://www.mywebsite.org";
        Listener<String> jsonListerner = new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String list) {

            }
        };

        ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.w("Volley Error", error.getMessage());
            }
        };

        StringRequest fileRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, requestURL, jsonListerner,errorListener){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("token", account.getToken());
                return params;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                // do not add anything here
                return headers;
            }
        };
        requestManager.add(fileRequest);
```

In the code Snippet above I used Post Method:

My answer is base on my experience and so take note:

1.) When using POST method use "StringRequest" instead of "JsonObjectRequest"

2.) inside getHeaders Override the value with an Empty HashMap

```
 example snippet:

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("token", account.getToken());
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            // do not add anything here
            return headers;
        }
```

And everything works in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I've got this error and now Iit's been fixed. I did what is told in [this link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50382/requestforupdate-always-returns-400). What you need to do is

1. go to src/com/android/volley/toolbox/BasicNetwork.java
2. Change the following lines

```js
 if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 299) {
     throw new IOException();
 }
```

with

```
 if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 405) {
     throw new IOException();
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed this params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

This is my Code Change.

```
@Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            if(!isLogout) {
                params.put("username", username);
                params.put("password", password);
                params.put("grant_type", "password");
            } else {
            }
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            if(isLogout) {
                params.put("Authorization", "bearer "+LibraryDataModel.getToken());
            }else {
            // Removed this line
            // params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            }
            return params;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android 2.3 there is a problem using Base64.encodeToString() as it introduces a new line in HTTP header. See my response [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23573692/authorization-header-on-2-3-4-gets-400-bad-request/34339639#34339639) here in SO.

Short answer: Don't use Base64.encodeToString() but put the already encoded String there.

Answer (score 0):

I have find a solution if you are using postman for hitting the api and your api have defined serializer  field like skill = serializers.JSONField() then that type of error occurred-

**Solution For POSTMAN-**
you just add binary=True inside JSONField ex- **skill = serializers.JSONField(binary=True)**

Solution for Android or other client then-
you just remove binary=True inside JSONField ex- **skill = serializers.JSONField()**

Answer (score 0):

Somertimes this error 400 is arise due to Request type so you need to change the `Request.Method.GET` to `Request.Method.POST` and than it works like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

Check if you are using correct SDK

For Android Studio / IntelliJIDEA:

```
File -> Project Structure -> Project -> Project SDK 
Modules -> Check each modules "Module SDK"
```

Preferably, you should use "Google API (x.x)" instead of Android API