# Android Volley gives me 400 error code (Bad Request)

Tags: android, json, android-volley, postman, bad-request

I am trying to make **POST** request to my app using `Volley` but it says

```
E/Volley﹕ [9988] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for http://test_url/SendMessage
```

But it perfectly working in `PostMan`.

**Snapshot of Postman:**

[image]

**Here is my Code:**

```
public JSONObject getJsonObject() {
        Map<String, Object> postParam = new HashMap<>();
        postParam.put("Recipients", new String[]{authorId + ":I"});
        postParam.put("Subject", etSubject.getText().toString());
        postParam.put("Text", etMessage.getText().toString());
        postParam.put("MessageState", "N");
        postParam.put("ParentId", "");
        postParam.put("PrivateMessageGuid", GUID);
        Log.i("JSON Parameter ===", Utils.getRequestJSONObject(postParam).toString());
        return Utils.getRequestJSONObject(postParam);
    }
```

**JSON Parameter ===**  `{"PrivateMessageGuid":"ac74df70-77d8-4281-a723-5c3c65f4d212",
 "Text":"hello test",
 "MessageState":"N","Subject":"Re: Hello Sundar","Recipients":["311:I"],"ParentId":""}`

**Main Code:**

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Constants.ReplyMessageUrl, getJsonObject(),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Message Send", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.try_again), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Authorization", mApp.getTokenType() + " " + mApp.getAccessToken());
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
            return headers;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue mRequestQueue = mApp.getRequestQueue();
    mRequestQueue.add(jsonReq);
```

Please help me to get solution. Thank you.

Comment: seems duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21739276/android-volley-gives-me-400-error

Comment: @random i saw that question

Comment: @Viks did you got any solutions am also getting same

Answer (score 0):

Install wireshark and compare both request in it to see the difference in live traffic. + Preferably use GSON with class done based on what is in getJsonObject()