# Android Volley ServerError

Tags: android, json, android-volley

[image]I am posting data all strings to varchar variables in server, but i am getting volley server error or badnetwork performance error 417.

I am using the following fuction to call the server, help me out if there is an error.

```
public void signUpWS() {
    avi.show();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(StringRequest.Method.POST, Constants.SIGN_UP, new Response.Listener<String>() {


        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Snackbar.make(mainlayout, response.toString(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("Responce from server", response.toString());
            avi.hide();
            if (!response.toString().contains("User")) {
                spEdit.putString(getString(R.string.uaccount), response.toString());
                spEdit.commit();
                Intent intent = new Intent(SignUp.this, Products.class);
                intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.uemail), Email_Address);
                intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.uphone), Phone_Number);
                intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.upass), Password);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            avi.hide();
            Log.e("Volley Error", error.toString());
            if (error.toString().contains("NoConnectionError")) {
                Snackbar.make(mainlayout, "Internet Not Available!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Snackbar.make(mainlayout, "Webservice not responding!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }) {
       @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return headers;
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
            String name[] = Name.split(" ");
            String first = "", last = "";
            boolean firstb = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
                if (firstb) {
                    first += name[i];
                    firstb = false;
                } else {
                    if (i == name.length - 1) {
                        last = name[i];
                    } else {
                        first += " ";
                        first += name[i];
                    }
                }
            }
            data.put("FirstName", first);
            data.put("LastName", last);
            data.put("LoginName", Login_Name);
            data.put("PrimaryEmail", Email_Address);
            data.put("PrimaryPasscode", Encrypted_Password);
            data.put("SecondaryPasscode", Encrypted_Password);
            data.put("PhoneNumber", Phone_Number);
            data.put("PrimaryCellNumber", Phone_Number);
            data.put("AccountType", UserType);
            data.put("ProfileRateSequence", "" + 0);
            data.put("MemberShipType", "BASIC");
            data.put("CityName", "null");
            data.put("CountryId", "" + 0);
            data.put("StateId", "" + 0);
            data.put("IsVerified", "" + 1);
            data.put("IsBlocked", "" + 0);
            data.put("IsBlackListed", "" + 0);
            data.put("IsActive", "" + 1);
            data.put("IsDeleted", "" + 0);

            return data;
        }
    };

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, REQ_TAG);
}[![The Error which i get on logcat.][1]][1]
```

Comment: 400 means bad request, try to perform that request, with exact same parameters/header in PostMan, and see what's the result, you might find out you're setting something wrong.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21739276/android-volley-gives-me-400-error

Comment: @LucaNicoletti is there a chance that there may be an error in webservices ?? or i am setting the request wrong?

Comment: because i am also getting an error in postman.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're asking something the server can not handle, read web services' API careful

Comment: @LucaNicoletti i have removed that error, regarding parameters. but still i am getting the error.

Comment: @LucaNicoletti now check it please. and thanks for your time.

Comment: The error has nothing to deal with your API calls. It's saying that you're missing some files. Make a google search about that error, but it's nothing to deal with Volley imho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not passing some parameters, which were mandatory for the APi's to call, therefore i was getting the expectation failed error.