# HTTPS Volley Invalid header issue

Tags: java, android, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

Before all : if you don't know the exact answer so just give me advice how to check. Thanks

I have alreary tried a lot of different way how to implement ssl to my volley request but without success.

I can not understand way I get this error

`ResponseJsonString = <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
                                                                  <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
                                                                  <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
                                                                  <BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Header</h2>
                                                                  <hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name.</p>
                                                                  </BODY></HTML>`

So step by step my code implementation

This is how I get the volley queue

```
mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this, new SslHurlStuck(SslUtils.KEYSTORE, SslUtils.PASSWORD_SSL, this));
```

there is my `SslHurlStuck`

```
package utils.ssl;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

import utils.global.AppUtils;


public class SslHurlStuck extends HurlStack
{
private final static String TAG = SslHurlStuck.class.getSimpleName();

private String mTrustStoreAssetName;
private String mTrustStorePassword;
private Context mContext;

public SslHurlStuck(final String iTrustStoreAssetName, final String iTrustStorePassword, Context iContext)
{
    super();

    mTrustStoreAssetName = iTrustStoreAssetName;
    mTrustStorePassword = iTrustStorePassword;
    mContext = iContext;
}

@Override
protected HttpURLConnection createConnection(URL url) throws IOException
{
    HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    try
    {
        urlConnection = new PinnedCertificateHttpsURLConnectionFactory(mContext).createHttpsURLConnection(url.toString(), mTrustStoreAssetName, mTrustStorePassword);
    }
    catch (Throwable iThrowable)
    {
        AppUtils.printLog(Log.ERROR, TAG, iThrowable.getMessage());
    }

    return urlConnection;
}
}
```

And eventually there is my `PinnedCertificateHttpsURLConnectionFactory`

```
package utils.ssl;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import java.net.URL;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

 import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import utils.global.AppUtils;
import webServices.global.RequestStringBuilder;


public class PinnedCertificateHttpsURLConnectionFactory
{
private final static String TAG = PinnedCertificateHttpsURLConnectionFactory.class.getSimpleName();

private final Context mContext;

public PinnedCertificateHttpsURLConnectionFactory(Context iContext)
{
    mContext = iContext;
}

HttpsURLConnection createHttpsURLConnection(String urlString, final String iTrustStoreAssetName, final String iTrustStorePassword) throws Throwable
{
    // Initialize the trust manager factory instance with our trust store
    // as source of certificate authorities and trust material.
    KeyStore trustStore = new TrustStoreFactory(iTrustStoreAssetName, iTrustStorePassword, mContext).createTrustStore();
    String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
    trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);

    // Initialize the SSL context.
    TrustManager[] wrappedTrustManagers = getWrappedTrustManagers(trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers());
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance(SslUtils.PROTOCOL_TLS);
    sslContext.init(null, wrappedTrustManagers, null);

    // Create the https URL connection.
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
    urlConnection.setHostnameVerifier(getHostnameVerifier());

    return urlConnection;
}

// Let's assume your server app is hosting inside a server machine
// which has a server certificate in which "Issued to" is "localhost",for example.
// Then, inside verify method you can verify "localhost".
// If not, you can temporarily return true
private HostnameVerifier getHostnameVerifier()
{
    return new HostnameVerifier()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session)
        {
            HostnameVerifier hv = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();

            String localHost = SslUtils.SSL_LOCAL_HOST_DEV;

            if (RequestStringBuilder.isEnvironmentProd())
            {
                localHost = SslUtils.SSL_LOCAL_HOST_PROD;
            }

            return hv.verify(localHost, session);
            //              return hv.verify("localhost", session);
            //              return true;
        }
    };
}

private TrustManager[] getWrappedTrustManagers(TrustManager[] trustManagers)
{
    final X509TrustManager originalTrustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0];

    final X509TrustManager x509TrustManager = new X509TrustManager()
    {
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers()
        {
            return originalTrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers();
        }

        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
        {
            try
            {
                if (certs != null && certs.length > 0)
                {
                    for (X509Certificate cer : certs)
                    {
                        cer.checkValidity();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    originalTrustManager.checkClientTrusted(certs, authType);
                }
            }
            catch (CertificateException e)
            {
                AppUtils.printLog(Log.ERROR, TAG, "checkClientTrusted" + e.toString());
            }
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
        {
            try
            {
                if (certs != null && certs.length > 0)
                {
                    for (X509Certificate cer : certs)
                    {
                        cer.checkValidity();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    originalTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(certs, authType);
                }
            }
            catch (CertificateException e)
            {
                AppUtils.printLog(Log.ERROR, TAG, "checkServerTrusted" + e.toString());
            }
        }
    };

    return new TrustManager[] {x509TrustManager};
}
}
```

And last one `TrustStoreFactory`

```
public class TrustStoreFactory
{
private String mTrustStoreAssetName;
private String mTrustStorePassword;

private Context mContext;

public TrustStoreFactory(final String iTrustStoreAssetName, final String iTrustStorePassword, final Context iContext)
{
    mTrustStoreAssetName = iTrustStoreAssetName;
    mTrustStorePassword = iTrustStorePassword;
    mContext = iContext;
}

KeyStore createTrustStore() throws Throwable
{
    // Retrieve the trust store file from the assets.
    InputStream inputStream = mContext.getAssets().open(mTrustStoreAssetName);

    try
    {
        // Create a key store with the retrieved input stream.
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(SslUtils.KEYSTORE_EXTENSION_BKS);

        trustStore.load(inputStream, mTrustStorePassword.toCharArray());

        return trustStore;
    }
    finally
    {
            inputStream.close();
    }
}
}
```

So, question is , what am I doing wrong?

My keystore consist 2 cer files, I tried different combinations to add the cer to the keystore... but nothing was changed.

Actually I don't think that there is a problems with a code, I think some issue with certificates , but I can not understand what exactly, and how to fix it

And also what is intresting that in iOS the same ssl checking work in another way, we just need to get certificate from response and then `getPublicKey()` on it, and compare if public key from response certificate equal to certificate public key that consist within app... But in android it is much more difficult...

Feel free to ask

Comment: What is the URL you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So eventyally in my case, I don't know why , but I just deleted `Content-type` header with the value from the response, and all is ok.

My answer was found here

[Android Volley gives me 400 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21739276/android-volley-gives-me-400-error)

Answer (score 0):

The Content-Type header is not treated the same way as other headers by Volley. In particular, overriding getHeaders() to change the content type does not always work. [Check this ans for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26246558/7301510)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
```